# Python: tqdm - 2 level progress bar leaves empty lines even after setting leave=False

Tags: python, command-line, progress-bar, tqdm

how can i have 2 progress bars, the latter which is a sub-progress to be displayed nicely[image]

i don't want those empty lines

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych how should i show the output then?

Answer (score 1):

#### Use the `position` parameter in tqdm

This tells tqdm which is the "outer" loop and which the "inner".

Use `position = 0` for the outer one, and `position = 1` for the inner.

#### Play around with the various types of `tqdm`

I have frequently had this problem and I have always solved it. However there is no particular rhyme or reason, to what works best. It depends on where your notebook is, e.g. local computer (and how you are accessing it, e.g. VS Code or JupyterLab, Jupyter Notebook), Colab, Kaggle, etc

Try these:

```
from tqdm import trange # This is probably what you are using now

from tqdm.notebook import trange

from tqdm.autonotebook import trange
```

#### Make sure you are not printing *anything* inside the loops

That definitely mangles it all up.

You have commented out the print statement, but is there *any* chance that a function you call may be printing something?

To test this possibility, delete the meat of the code and replace it with some `sleep`s or something.

Comment: I ended up re-using the inner progress bar. (bar.reset())
I was using the tdqm of from tdqm.notebook itself. setting position did kinda work, but not the way i wanted. will tweek around more.

Comment: whats the difference btw notebook and autonotebook?

Comment: I've never properly understood the difference, and as a result never really understood Which one is most likely to work in each environment. All still a mystery to me.